# How do I interpret MRAE (Accuracy measure)?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, accuracy

Can somebody explain to me how I would interpret the result of the MRAE.

In my textbook the MRAE is defined as followed:

$$
MRAE= {1 \over n}\left(\sum_{t=1}^n \left|{e_t \over e_t^*}\right|\right)
$$

with $e_t=\text{actual value}-\text{forecasted value}$
and $e_t^*$ being the benchmarking method where $e_t^*=e_{t-1}$.

Now consider these simple example:
Example 1:
| actual | forecast | error |
|--------|----------|---------|
| 10 | 5 | 5 |
|8 | 4 | 4 |
|20 | 10| 10|

this would result in
$$
MRAE= {1 \over 2}\cdot\left({4 \over 5}+{10 \over 4}\right)=1,65
$$

Example 2:
| actual | forecast | error |
|--------|----------|---------|
| 10 | 1 | 9 |
|8 | 1 | 7 |
|20 | 1| 19|

this would result in
$$
MRAE= {1 \over 2}\cdot\left({7 \over 9}+{19 \over 7}\right)=1,75
$$

Now what does this tell me? Am I 65% (75% respectively) better than the benchmarking method? And if so, what does that tell me about the actual forecasting method?

Answer (score 1):

The MRAE is a particularly unhelpful way to measure forecast accuracy. For any reasonable forecasting method, the errors can be positive or negative, so the distribution of the errors will have non-zero density at 0. Therefore the ratio of the two errors in the MRAE will have an undefined mean and infinite variance. Consequently the MRAE cannot converge and is not a consistent estimator of anything. This is one of the problems I pointed out in [Hyndman & Koehler (2006)](https://robjhyndman.com/publications/another-look-at-measures-of-forecast-accuracy/).

I suggest you do not use the MRAE, despite some textbooks still including it.